# Changing a Qt AbstractListModel without using in-place editing

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I currently have a QtAbstractListModel subcliass (shortened for clarity):

```
class HolidayTask;

class HolidayTaskModel: public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit HolidayTaskModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~HolidayTaskModel();

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const;

    bool insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex());
    bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex());

    bool setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value,
                 int role = Qt::EditRole);

private:
    QVector<HolidayTask*> m_items;

};
```

Where `HolidayTask` is the items I'm containing. I'm trying to figure out what needs to be reimplemented for this use case:

1. The model is modifiable, but *not with in place editing in the view*: another widget (not a *View subclass) will do the editing, outside from the view this model will be shown in;
2. It needs to implement not only appending (that would be easy) but also inserting and reordering.

In the case of appending, it would be very easy to make an `appendTask` function that calls `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows`, however at least inserting and/or removing is not as trivial.

Most of the code examples I've found around deal with in-place editing (`createEditor`, etc.), which, as I've wrote above, is not what I'm needing. What should I be implementing to  modify this model to accomplish this task? Alternatively, are there any code examples that show this modus operandi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to edit your model data using views, you don't need to implement `insertRows`, `removeRows` and `setData`. Instead, you should create your own modifying functions, e.g. `add_task(HolidayTask* task)`, `set_task(int row, HolidayTask* task)` and `remove_task(int row)`. In these functions you need to change `m_items` value to reflect data changes. (Besides, your should switch from `QVector` to `QList` if you need insertions and deletions from the middle of the list to be fast). Additionally, you should notify views about the changes:

- Call `beginRemoveRows` before removing a row and `endRemoveRows` after that.
- Call `beginInsertRows` before inserting a row and `endInsertRows` after that.
- Call `emit dataChanged(...)` after changing data.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting is like appending, just with a row != m_items.size():

```
void HolidayTaskModel::addTask(HolidayTask* task)
{
    const int row = ...find position...
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row, row);
    m_items.insert(row, task);
    endInsertRows();
}
```

Remove a task:

```
void HolidayTaskModel::removeTask(HolidayTask* task)
{
    const int row = m_items.indexOf(task);
    if (row == -1)
        return;
    beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row);
    delete m_items[row]; //only if the item is owned by the model
    m_items.remove(row);
    endRemoveRows();         
}
```

For reordering, it depends on your exact use case, for moving single items use [beginMoveRows()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginMoveRows)/[endMoveRows()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endMoveRows), for sorting reimplement [sort()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#sort) or, often easier, leave the items in the base model unsorted and let a [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSortFilterProxyModel.html) proxy do the sorting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on sorting, I'll check out the proxy models.